# Why does jQuery prevent a propper 301 redirect?

Tags: jquery, apache, jquery-mobile, redirect

I want to 301 redirect after form post with loaded jquery and jquery mobile libraries in the html file.

This somehow does not work as expected, since the destination changes, but the URL stays inside the browser, which creates several problems thereafter.

HTML file, saved as UTF-8 unix:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="DE">
<head>
    <title>redirect test</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <form action ="/subapp_search/filter_results_redir.php" method="POST">
        <input type="submit">test
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP action file, saved as UTF-8 unix, name: /dir/filter_results_redir.php

```
<?php
    header("Location: /", TRUE, 301);
    exit;
?>
```

With this code, the Browser URL window will show the POST URL: `dir/filter_results_redir.php` and redirect.

Removing either one of the two jQuery libraries will solve the problem and the displayed URL will change to `/` and redirect

I tried absolute and relative URLs. Servier is Apache 2.4.18

```
Request URL: http://rex.local/subapp_search/filter_results_redir.php
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 301 Moved Permanently
Remote Address: 192.143.56.200:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 19 Mar 2019 05:51:07 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Location: /
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
AlexaToolbar-ALX_NS_PH: AlexaToolbar/alx-4.0.3
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Cookie: user_cls=a%3A9%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bi%3A961992%3Bi%3A1%3Bi%3A961993%3Bi%3A2%3Bi%3A961994%3Bi%3A3%3Bi%3A961995%3Bi%3A4%3Bi%3A961996%3Bi%3A5%3Bi%3A961997%3Bi%3A6%3Bi%3A961998%3Bi%3A7%3Bi%3A962004%3Bi%3A8%3Bi%3A962005%3B%7D; test_cookie=e8e; new_cl=vfn5kj4stc115ri78td0qt8r13; findix_counter=a%3A5%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A6%3A%22961944%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A6%3A%22961960%22%3Bi%3A2%3Bs%3A6%3A%22961940%22%3Bi%3A3%3Bs%3A6%3A%22960238%22%3Bi%3A4%3Bs%3A6%3A%22961952%22%3B%7D; session_localrexDE=4fb1bbbfa7db5a268d50d6a3ca4fef0b
Host: rex.local
Origin: http://rex.local
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://rex.local/subapp_search/filter_results_redir.php
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: Just guessiing, try: `<form action="*Your redir link*" method="POST" data-ajax="false">`

Comment: This is a good hint, I just found it as well. However, the  exact same line of code does work while the other does not. I don't understand. I copied the form code with the ajax info from another page and found that it is working, then I added it to my form, but it did not. After 30 minutes I figured it is the exact same line of code but it is behaving differnt.

Answer (score 0):

I finaly solved it, but I do not understand the problem. The same line of code works, while the other one does not.

The first thign to do is, to add the data-ajax="false" to the code. But this did not solve it.

This code does not work:

```
<form method="post" action="/filter_results_redir.php" data-ajax=”false” >
```

This code does work:

```
<form method="post" action="/filter_results_redir.php" data-ajax="false">
```

It looks exactly the same. Copy pasting did not work, I wrote the line again letter by letter, then it worked.